# Angular2 Localized URL, Named Routes

Tags: angularjs, angular, localization, internationalization, url-routing

We are currently trying to have named routes in our SPA. Depending on the language, we should have:

```
www.website.com/help
www.website.com/ayuda
www.website.com/hifen
```

Also, in our references, we should be able to configure:

`href=“/help” 
href=“/ayuda” 
href="/hilfe"`

Depending on the language

Does Angular2 router support this?
(if not, how can we achieve it?)

Comment: Did you try to use translate library like e.g ng2-translate to make you website multi-language?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a package called `localize-router` which extends `ng2-translate` and should do exactly what you're looking for. Please have in mind that it's still in progress so it's probably not recommended for the production yet.

Please find it here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/localize-router

You can use pipes to translate route links

```
<a [routerLink]="['user', userId, 'profile'] | localize">{{'USER_PROFILE' | translate}}</a>

<a [routerLink]="['about' | localize]">{{'ABOUT' | translate}}</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another package for the same purpose [@ngx-i18n-router/core](https://github.com/ngx-i18n-router/core), works with `static` translations as well as providing route translations through `http`.

Check it here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngx-i18n-router/core
supports lazy routes as well.

Pipe usage is same as above.